# Did Microsoft drop source-code annotation language (SAL) and calling convention from their function definition in MSDN

Tags: c++, msdn, sal

For example, the function definition of `SetWindowPos` used to be like so:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowPos(
  _In_      HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  _In_      int X,
  _In_      int Y,
  _In_      int cx,
  _In_      int cy,
  _In_      UINT uFlags
);
```

This used to be very clear on the calling convention and which parameters are optional/in/out, etc.

However, now the MSDN makes it much simpler, but drops the calling convention and SAL annotations like so:

```
BOOL SetWindowPos(
  HWND hWnd,
  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  int  X,
  int  Y,
  int  cx,
  int  cy,
  UINT uFlags
);
```

Question: Is there anyway to see the SAL annotations and the calling convention now? Why did they think to remove it though?

Comment: Offline help files still display SAL annotations and they are still used at actual declarations in header files.

Answer (score 0):

No, they didn't. With all do respect, I can see it. I am using MS 2019 Community installed well after this question was asked. And since no one answered, here are my 5 cents:

- Type this function anywhere in your code, assuming it is in scope.

[image]

- Select -> right-click -> Go To Declaration or hit Ctrl+F12.

[image]

- And you should be send to `WinUser.h`

[image]

If you still can't see SAL annotation, try to upgrade the include files...
...or simply install newer VS.
Community is FREE!